# Gulps gulp.watch not triggered for new or deleted files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

The following Gulpjs task works fine when editing files in the glob match:

```
// watch task.
gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.watch(src + '/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(src + '/img//**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', ['copy:images']);
    gulp.watch(src + '/less/*.less', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(src + '/templates/**/*.{swig,json}', ['html']);
});

// build task.
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.start('copy', 'scripts', 'less', 'htmlmin');
});
```

However it doesn't work (it's not triggered) for new or deleted files. Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**: even using grunt-watch plugin it seems not working:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return streamqueue(
        { objectMode: true },
        gulp.src([
            vendor + '/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            vendor + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
        ]),
        gulp.src([
            src + '/js/**/*.js'
        ]).pipe(plugins.uglify())
    )
    .pipe(plugins.concat(pkg.name + '.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/js/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function () {
    plugins.watch({glob: src + '/js/**/*.js'}, function () {
        gulp.start('scripts');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: Solved, it was [this issue](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/1). Globs starting with `./` (that was the value of `src`) seems not working ATM.

Comment: Would be great if you changed the accepted answer to the one from Nestor Urquiza.  It's the real answer here rather than adding an additional plugin

Comment: the answer by @alexk was the simplest, and didn't require the addition of `gulp-watch`, eg `gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', {cwd: src}, ['scripts']);`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**Edit:** Apparently `gulp.watch` does work with new or deleted files now.  It did not when the question was asked.

The rest of my answer still stands: `gulp-watch` is usually a better solution because it lets you perform specific actions only on the files that have been modified, while `gulp.watch` only lets you run complete tasks.  For a project of a reasonable size, this will quickly become too slow to be useful.

---

You aren't missing anything. `gulp.watch` does not work with new or deleted files.  It's a simple solution designed for simple projects.

To get file watching that can look for new files, use [the `gulp-watch` plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch), which is much more powerful.  Usage looks like this:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

// in a task
watch({glob: <<glob or array of globs>> })
        .pipe( << add per-file tasks here>> );

// if you'd rather rerun the whole task, you can do this:
watch({glob: <<glob or array of globs>>}, function() {
    gulp.start( <<task name>> );
});
```

Personally, I recommend the first option.  This allows for much faster, per-file processes.  It works great during development with livereload as long as you aren't concatenating any files.

You can wrap up your streams either using [my `lazypipe` library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/lazypipe), or simply using a function and [`stream-combiner`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/stream-combiner) like this:

```
var combine = require('stream-combiner');

function scriptsPipeline() {
    return combine(coffeeescript(), uglify(), gulp.dest('/path/to/dest'));
}

watch({glob: 'src/scripts/**/*.js' })
        .pipe(scriptsPipeline());
```

---

**UPDATE** October 15, 2014

As pointed out by @pkyeck below, apparently the 1.0 release of `gulp-watch` changed the format slightly, so the above examples should now be:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

// in a task
watch(<<glob or array of globs>>)
        .pipe( << add per-file tasks here>> );

// if you'd rather rerun the whole task, you can do this:
watch(<<glob or array of globs>>, function() {
    gulp.start( <<task name>> );
});
```

and

```
var combine = require('stream-combiner');

function scriptsPipeline() {
    return combine(coffeeescript(), uglify(), gulp.dest('/path/to/dest'));
}

watch('src/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(scriptsPipeline());
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but still can't get it to work. I'm new to Gulp (I've used Grunt a couple of times) and maybe my main task is wrong... dunno. See my updated question.

Comment: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/1 globs starting with './' not emitting. My src variable is exactly '-/'. Found the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Good catch on finding that bug.  Hopefully it will help if anyone else comes across it!

Comment: @JHannes What are you replying to?  That's what this answer is explaining.

Comment: dont forget to wrap the `watch()` function inside a `gulp.task("watch", ..)` so you can call it furthermore from terminal with `gulp watch`.

Comment: @OverZealous I think the interface was updated with v1.0 and this answer doesn't work anymore. Tried it with the new version, but watch wasn't triggered after creating a new file :(

Comment: @pkyeck It looks like they've pulled the `glob` property out of the options, which is a good choice.  I haven't switched to the `1.0` release yet, but I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @OverZealous thanks for the update - worked this out myself from their docs ;) but creating a new file inside e.g. Sublime wasn't recognized by the watch 'task' ...

Comment: @pkyeck Was the directory you were watching initially empty?  If so, [there's apparently a bug in `gaze` that prevents it from seeing new files in an initially empty dir](https://github.com/shama/gaze/pull/103)

Comment: It seems that this still isn't supported in Gulp 4.0.  This is very upsetting.

Comment: gulp.start is a call to a non-public API method.   Is there another way to execute tasks?

Comment: How can I *only* watch for new files? I don't want to watch for changes to existing files, just for creation of new ones

Comment: `gulp.watch` can certainly perform specific actions on modified files, not necessarily full tasks. This requires using streams themselves, which is annoying, though your `lazypipe` plugin makes it much easier for `gulp`.

Comment: couldn't make `gulp-watch` to work but `gulp.watch` with `cwd` hack works

Answer (score 87):

Both `gulp.watch()` and `require('gulp-watch')()` will trigger for new/deleted files however not if you use absolute directories. In my tests I did not use `"./"` for relative directories BTW.

Both won't trigger if whole directories are deleted though.

```
   var watch = require('gulp-watch');
   //Wont work for new files until gaze is fixed if using absolute dirs. It  won't trigger if whole directories are deleted though.
   //gulp.watch(config.localDeploy.path + '/reports/**/*', function (event) {

   //gulp.watch('src/app1/reports/**/*', function (event) {
   // console.log('*************************** Event received in gulp.watch');
   // console.log(event);
   // gulp.start('localDeployApp');
   });

   //Won't work for new files until gaze is fixed if using absolute dirs. It  won't trigger if whole directories are deleted though. See https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/104
   //watch(config.localDeploy.path + '/reports/**/*', function() {

   watch('src/krfs-app/reports/**/*', function(event) {
      console.log("watch triggered");
      console.log(event);
      gulp.start('localDeployApp');
   //});
```

Comment: It's interesting to pass the `cb` argument to `gulp.start`

Comment: Excellent and simple answer.

Comment: this did exactly what I needed without adding another dependency.

Comment: yup - so many gulp examples out there start with `./` in their paths - actually it seems like bad practice - https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/issues/1

Comment: Thank you for this. I was just racking my brain trying to get `gulp-watch` working properly to trigger on new files or deleted files. No need! `gulp.watch` does this. Removing all `./` from the paths cleared up issues. Awesome.

Comment: This should probably be the right answer - didn't really fancy installing another plugin to watch. Removed the ./ from all my globs and worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer, no extra module required or understanding of crazy syntax.

Answer (score 57):

If `src` is an absolute path (starting with `/`), your code is not going to detect new or deleted files. However there's still a way:

Instead of:

```
gulp.watch(src + '/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
```

write:

```
gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', {cwd: src}, ['scripts']);
```

and it will work!

Comment: The `{ cwd: src }` hint was my solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks a lot @alexk,  { cwd: src } solved my problem.

Comment: @DanielTonon did you put in inside an array of files by mistake? should be a direct parameter of `watch`

Comment: It can't be in an array? Well that sucks. What about exclusions? It's not possible to do gobbing with exclusions without putting the source files into an array.

Comment: Great answer.  To add further, if you don't want to change every glob pattern, just add `{cwd:'./'}` and leave the glob pattern as is so it would become `gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', {cwd: './'}, ['scripts']);`

Comment: It worked for new file, but it doesn't work for deleted file

Comment: lmao. I think I just found a bug. So `{cwd:'./'}` hack worked in one project. Then I ported package.json, gulp.js and other technical files into my boilerplate. And to my surprise gulp didn't register deletion and creation of files. I tinkered a little with it and decided to delete node_modules folder. After I deleted it and installed everything, it started to detect deletion and creation of new files. So if it doesn't work for you - try that.

Answer (score 7):

Globs must have a separate base directory specified and that base location must not be specified in the glob itself.

If you have `lib/*.js`, it'll look under the current working dir which is `process.cwd()`

Gulp uses Gaze to watch files and in the [Gulp API doc](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob-opts-tasks) we see that we can pass Gaze specific options to the watch function: `gulp.watch(glob[, opts], tasks)`

Now in the [Gaze doc](https://github.com/shama/gaze#properties) we can find that the current working dir (glob base dir) is the `cwd` option.

Which leads us to alexk's answer: 
`gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', {cwd: src}, ['scripts']);`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but I thought I'd throw the solution I came up with. None of the gulp plugins I found would notify me of new or renamed files. So I ended up wrapping monocle in a convenience function.

Here's an example of how that function is used:

```
watch({
    root: config.src.root,
    match: [{
      when: 'js/**',
      then: gulpStart('js')
    }, {
      when: '+(scss|css)/**',
      then: gulpStart('css')
    }, {
      when: '+(fonts|img)/**',
      then: gulpStart('assets')
    }, {
      when: '*.+(html|ejs)',
      then: gulpStart('html')
    }]
  });
```

I should note that gulpStart is also a convenience function I made.

And here is the actual watch module.

```
module.exports = function (options) {
  var path = require('path'),
      monocle = require('monocle'),
      minimatch = require('minimatch');

  var fullRoot = path.resolve(options.root);

  function onFileChange (e) {
    var relativePath = path.relative(fullRoot, e.fullPath);

    options.match.some(function (match) {
      var isMatch = minimatch(relativePath, match.when);
      isMatch && match.then();
      return isMatch;
    });
  }

  monocle().watchDirectory({
    root: options.root,
    listener: onFileChange
  });
};
```

Pretty simple, eh? The whole thing can be found over at my gulp starter kit: https://github.com/chrisdavies/gulp_starter_kit

Comment: Hey buddy, not enough people have given props for this!  It works like a charm, thank you very much.  (The answer leaves out what "gulpStart" does, so it can be confusing, if anyone is interested, just visit the link and head to the `utils` folder)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that it looks like gulp.watch only reports changed and deleted files on Windows but listens for new and deleted files by default on OSX:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/675

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'gulp-watch' for new/renamed/deleted files instead of gulp.watch

```
var gulpwatch = require('gulp-watch');
var source = './assets',  
destination = './dest';
gulp.task('copy-changed-assets', function() {
    gulpwatch(source+'/**/*', function(obj){
        gulp.src( obj.path, { "base": source})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
    });
});
```