# Automatically restart GulpJS watch when gulp file changes

Tags: build, gulp, gulp-watch

Lets say I have gulp watch running and I add a file to a task.  Is there any way to have the gulp watch process automatically restart since a task has changes?

Answer (score 2):

gulp.watch isn't working for new or deleted files.

In order to accomplish that, you can use gulp-watch plugin: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('live', function () {
    watch({glob: 'global/files/**/*.extension'}, function(files) {
      // Do stuffs
    });
});
```

This solution comes from this question:

[Gulps gulp.watch not triggered for new or deleted files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files)