# Gulp watch not working for subdirectory

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm use gulp.
I have a task

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.js'], ['scripts']);
});
```

I have same folder structure:

- app

  - modules

    - admin

      - adminCtrl.js
    - home

      - homeCtrl.js
- app.js

If I add file *.js or new subdirectory, for example, into 'modules/admin', gulp watch working, but, if I create new subdirectory in modules/, for example, 'about', and add into 'about' file, for example,  aboutCtrl.js, gulp watch is not working. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gulps gulp.watch not triggered for new or deleted files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files)

Comment: no. it's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your best option is to go ahead and rerun Gulp infrequently or after you add new directories. Seems like the 'gaze' library behind gulp-watch has issues related to this which they plan to resolve in a upcoming release. Ref: https://github.com/shama/gaze/issues/70

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what interests me. Only it is not clear how soon they will be able to fix it.

Comment: Those are concerns probably best handled in the gaze issue tracker. Not sure anyone on StackOverflow will be able to help you with a bug in a piece of software you don't maintain, beyond suggesting you avoid the bug entirely.

Comment: manually restart gulp or certain tasks. Other variations and does not remain. So while it is indeed the best. Thank U