# Gulp watch doesn't "feel" new files

Tags: javascript, pug, yeoman-generator-angular, gulp-watch

This is my **watch.js** as written by yeoman gulp-angular generator

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

function isOnlyChange(event) {
  return event.type === 'changed';
}

gulp.task('watch', ['scripts:watch', 'markups', 'inject'], function () {

  gulp.watch([path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'), 'bower.json'], ['inject-reload']);

  gulp.watch([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.css'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.scss')
  ], function(event) {
    if(isOnlyChange(event)) {
      gulp.start('styles-reload');
    } else {
      gulp.start('inject-reload');
    }
  });


  gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.jade'), ['markups']);

  gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'), function(event) {
    browserSync.reload(event.path);
  });
});
```

It works fine for already created files, but for some reason `gulp.watch` doesn't see the new ones (in particular `.jade`, but maybe also other types), eg.

```
myApp/src/components/header/headerView.jade
```

The only solution for me to run task as `markup` is to stop and restart `gulp serve`. Then gulp will recognizes changes in my `.jade` files

Comment: Maybe `'/app/**/*.jade'` doesn't match `myApp/src/components/header/headerView.jade` ?

Comment: it does, see globbing syntax (and anyway, it works for already existing files)

Comment: If it works for old files, then it must be a watch bug.

Comment: Maybe yes, found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files