# GULP : how to watch for new images while using browserSync?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync, gulp-imagemin

I can't figure out how to watch for new files with **gulp-watch** and apply **gulp-image** while using my **browserSync**... When I add a new image in my image folder (./fixtures/*), nothing happen. I would do it manually in the command line but I would have to close my browserSync (not really a viable solution). So... here's what my gulpfile.js looks like :

```
var input = "./scss/*.scss";
var output = "./"
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sassdoc = require('sassdoc');
var image = require('gulp-image');

// scss + sourceMaps

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src(input)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(output))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

// scss + browserSync

gulp.task('serve', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
          baseDir: output
        }
    });

    gulp.watch(input, ['styles']);
    gulp.watch("./**/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// sassDoc activation

gulp.task('sassdoc', function () {
  return gulp.src(input)
    .pipe(sassdoc());
});

// image minification

gulp.task('image', function() {
  gulp.watch('./fixtures/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}', function() {
    gulp.src('./fixtures/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
      .pipe(image())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./img'));
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve', 'image']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the seve task like so:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {

  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: output
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(input, ['styles']);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
  // gulp.watch('./fixtures/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}', ['image']);
  gulp.watch('fixtures/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}', {cwd: './'} ['image']);
});
```

and then simplify the 'image' task to :

```
gulp.task('image', function() {
 return gulp.src('./fixtures/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}')
  .pipe(image())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./img'));
});
```

You probably want to add gulp-cached or gulp-remember to your image pipeline so you are not minifying all images each time one is changed or added.

Also, remember to add return statements to your tasks like I did with image; the 'styles' task needs a return statement.

**EDIT** : See the edit above, it looks like gulp.watch doesn't like a glob starting with "./" from other questions such as [gulp.watch not watching added or deleted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files).  I haven't tested this for myself though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's working when I change the name of a file in the fixtures directory... but, it's not working when I add a file. Any idea ?