# My gulpfile can edit (change) and delete file, but dont copy new (add) files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I tried with gulp.watch and watch (gulp-watch) but when i add the new file, dont copy in dest.

How i can to do this?

Thnks!

PD: I use version 3.9.1

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  for(var i = 0; i < origen_web.length ; i++) {
    var source = '../..' + '/dir' + '/**/*';
    var dist   = '../../dist';

    watch(source, function(obj){
      copyFiles(obj, source, dist);
    });
  }
}

function copyFiles(source, dist, obj) {

  gulp.src(source)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
}
```

Sorry, this is my code more and less.

Comment: Could you post an example of your gulp file?

Comment: I posted a little code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files

Comment: Yes, I saw, but I tried and it doenst work.
I'm doing some changes and its work now, I dont know the cause.

Thnks!

Comment: Show what you tried that didn't work.  [Edit your question to show what else you tried.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use absolute path to directories.

Duplicate question of 
[Gulps gulp.watch not triggered for new or deleted files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yep, I use this example but work if its copy all folder, if I copy file for file changed, dont work with new files :S

Comment: Does it throw anything? Maybe script doesn't have permission to those files? Can you just use nodejs fs APIs to copy the file just to check? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: I posted a little code and yep, I have permission because this files (add) is in the same folder that the copied files.

Comment: This is old info that gulp.watch does not work on new or deleted files, see the duplicate question.  No need for gulp-watch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try with this.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  for(var i = 0; i < origen_web.length ; i++) {
    var source = '../..' + '/dir' + '/**/*';
    var dist   = '../../dist';

    watch(source, function(obj){
      copyFiles(obj, source, dist);
    });
  }
}

function copyFiles(source, dist, obj) {

  return gulp.src(source) // <-- here you force gulp to return the value
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
  .pipe(notify({message: "This message is triggered if the data has been transferred"}));
}
```