# gulp watch added files

Tags: node.js, gulp

I want gulp to track folders for new files (not just file updates). I tried to use `gulp.watch` and `gulp-watch` plugin, both not working for adding new files.

I'm going to add simplified versions of my gulp (for example I'll use only images folder)

First option with `gulp.wath`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

let dev = true;

// clean the build directory
gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['public/build']));

// proceed and copy all images to build directory
gulp.task('images', () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/images'));
});


// build for development with watching for a changes
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    runSequence(['clean'], ['images'], () => {
        console.log('WATCHING FOR A CHANGES');

        gulp.watch([
            'assets/images/**/*',
        ]).on('change', reload);
    });
});
```

Second option with `gulp.wath`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

let dev = true;

// clean the build directory
gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['public/build']));

// proceed and copy all images to build directory
gulp.task('images', () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/images'));
});


// build for development with watching for a changes
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    runSequence(['clean'], ['images'], () => {
        console.log('WATCHING FOR A CHANGES');

         gulp.watch('assets/images/**/*', ['images']);
    });
});
```

Opotion with `gulp-wath`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');

let dev = true;

// clean the build directory
gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['public/build']));

// proceed and copy all images to build directory
gulp.task('images', () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/images/**/*')
        .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/images'));
});


// build for development with watching for a changes
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    runSequence(['clean'], ['images'], () => {
        console.log('WATCHING FOR A CHANGES');

        watch('assets/images/**/*', function () {
            gulp.start('images')
        });
    });
});
```

neither of the provided options works for newly added files, the third option even do not track file changes at all but depends on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391527/gulps-gulp-watch-not-triggered-for-new-or-deleted-files) it should work.

Comment: Which version of gulp are you running?

Comment: Gulp version is 3.9.1